# How can I draw a perspective-correct quad?

Tags: textures, directx, xna-4.0, perspective

I'm trying to draw a quad in 2D (in SharpDX, but that is basically XNA). But texture correction is not working, and I'm getting only an affine textured quad.

[image]

I'm using `BasicEffect` to render it.

```
BasicTextureEffect = new BasicEffect(Device)
{
    Alpha = 1.0f,

    TextureEnabled = true,
    LightingEnabled = false,
    VertexColorEnabled = true,

    Projection = Matrix.OrthoOffCenterLH(0.0f, ScreenWidth, ScreenHeight, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f),
};
```

It is an 2D isometric game. I have pseudo-3D coordinates in isometric world (it's a shadow on the ground) converted to screen space, and then rendered using `DrawQuad`.

Do I need to set-up view (or projection?) somehow, to real 3D (emulate the isometric camera), and then draw this quad in 3D coordinates instead? How eventually? Or is there a way to correct this in 2D?

**Update:**

I've uploaded the actual partial screen-shot (Figure A), for you to see it's almost the same. (I cut it a bit, but it goes all to the corner)

[image: Figure A]   [image: Figure B] 
            Figure A                                         Figure B

**Update 2:**

I can confirm now, that plain SharpDX (XNA) `BasicEffect` does this with just plain UW mapping (4 corners of a square), and plain `DrawQuad`. I've temporarily changed it to include center point, and I do draw 4 triangles instead of 2 (Figure B), this reduces effect to minimum, but it's still there. It still needs to be solved, because I won't be using it only on shadow.

Comment: why texture perspective correction not working ?

Comment: I really don't know. The effect (on already barely visible shadow) was noticed only by accident, when I changed it to checkerboard texture. It isn't pronounced at all, but it's definitely recognizable as affine. You can't ask me question that I'm basically asking. Why is it not working IS the question? :)

Comment: Similar to this question from SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242507/perspective-correct-texturing-of-trapezoid-in-opengl-es-2-0

Comment: I actually read that, but I wasn't able to conclude what to do in DirectX, it seems OpenGL specific as is the solution presented.

Comment: Indeed, did you find Nathan Reed's article about it?  http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/

Comment: So is the problem in BasicEffect, or my settings, because this suggests custom shader? I would think that perspective correction would be a default thing. (I didn't read that before btw, thanks)

Comment: My guess at this problem is in the question. Maybe the orthographic setup of projection (on screen) doesn't produce perspective correct textures. In that case I would need to set it up somehow, to match 2D isometric view, and render it in true 3D (not in 2D screen projection).

Comment: Before you try anything else, make sure your texcoording is not wrong.  Try a non-symmetrical image and see if it doesn't come out chopped in the middle.

Comment: Hi, I'm using shadow of the silhouette of a man. I did this pattern only to show the deformation (because in 20% alpha shadow wasn't much apparent, even less so after center point correction). So I know it is correct mapping. I even tried pure values manually to test my sanity.

Comment: Check this out (actual shadow, no way I get it wrong): http://i.imgur.com/fw62SPe.png (you cannot even see the distortion, I didn't know about it for 2 months).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've changed the shader according to [the article suggested by Seth Battin](http://www.reedbeta.com/blog/2012/05/26/quadrilateral-interpolation-part-1/). Now it performs perspectively correct quad texturing. Phew, bacon delivered:

[image]

For the future generations that may never happen. The input is in a form of the line vertexes A1/A2, B1/B2 that creates diagonals (rather then sequential vertexes):

```
public static Vector3 DrawPerspectiveCorrectQuad(VertexWithPerspective v1, VertexWithPerspective v2, VertexWithPerspective v3, VertexWithPerspective v4)
{
    // detects intersection of two diagonal lines
    Single divisor = (v4.Position.Y - v3.Position.Y) * (v2.Position.X - v1.Position.X) - (v4.Position.X - v3.Position.X) * (v2.Position.Y - v1.Position.Y);
    Single ua = ((v4.Position.X - v3.Position.X) * (v1.Position.Y - v3.Position.Y) - (v4.Position.Y - v3.Position.Y) * (v1.Position.X - v3.Position.X)) / divisor;
    Single ub = ((v2.Position.X - v1.Position.X) * (v1.Position.Y - v3.Position.Y) - (v2.Position.Y - v1.Position.Y) * (v1.Position.X - v3.Position.X)) / divisor;

    // calculates the intersection point
    Single centerX = v1.Position.X + ua * (v2.Position.X - v1.Position.X);
    Single centerY = v1.Position.Y + ub * (v2.Position.Y - v1.Position.Y);
    Vector3 center = new Vector3(centerX, centerY, 0.5f);

    // determines distances to center for all vertexes
    Single d1 = (v1.Position - center).Length();
    Single d2 = (v2.Position - center).Length();
    Single d3 = (v3.Position - center).Length();
    Single d4 = (v4.Position - center).Length();

    // calculates quotients used as w component in uvw texture mapping
    v1.TextureCoordinate *= Single.IsNaN(d2) || d2 == 0.0f ? 1.0f : (d1 + d2)/d2;
    v2.TextureCoordinate *= Single.IsNaN(d1) || d1 == 0.0f ? 1.0f : (d2 + d1)/d1;
    v3.TextureCoordinate *= Single.IsNaN(d4) || d4 == 0.0f ? 1.0f : (d3 + d4)/d4;
    v4.TextureCoordinate *= Single.IsNaN(d3) || d3 == 0.0f ? 1.0f : (d4 + d3)/d3;

    // this is just PrimitiveBatch<VertexWithPerspective>
    // where VertexWithPerspective is basically VertexPositionTextureColor
    // with Vector3 (uvw) instead of Vector2 (uv) for texture coordinates
    // note: you need to create VertexWithPerspective yourself (decompilation ftw)
    PerspectivePrimitives.DrawQuad(v1, v3, v2, v4);
}
```