# Textured trapezoid in Monogame DirectX

Tags: xna, textures, directx, hlsl, monogame

I'm working on a 2D game, so most of the graphics are sprites. However, some elements are drawn using trianglestrips in Orthographic projection. The thing is that I can't do a 3D projection because the coordinates of the vertices have to line up with some of the sprites in the game.

I'm running into a problem trying to texture these triangles. 
I understand how the texturing works, so I understand that the interpolation causes the effect:

[image: Trapezoid with texture]

For now I have no idea where to start. I Googled and looked for similar questions, but all seem to deal with fixing this in OpenGL. [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892120/texture-mapping-a-trapezoid-with-a-square-texture-in-opengl) I have no clue how to apply it to Monogame/DirectX. I also don't know how to start with a shader, as I don't really grasp how to interpolate across two triangles.

If it makes the issue easier, I don't care for accurate perspective, just that the texture is correctly stretched over the two triangles.

So far I have only used a `BasicEffect` like this:

```
        checkered = Content.Load<Texture2D>("checkered");

        basicEffect = new BasicEffect(GraphicsDevice);
        basicEffect.VertexColorEnabled = true;
        basicEffect.TextureEnabled = true;
        basicEffect.Texture = checkered;
        basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter
        (0, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width,     // left, right
        GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height, 0,    // bottom, top
        0, 1);
```

The draw function is like this (nothing special):

```
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.Green);

        basicEffect.CurrentTechnique.Passes[0].Apply();

        VertexPositionColorTexture[] vertices = new VertexPositionColorTexture[4];

        vertices[0].Position = new Vector3(100,50, 0);
        vertices[1].Position = new Vector3(200, 50, 0);
        vertices[2].Position = new Vector3(50,200, 0);
        vertices[3].Position = new Vector3(250, 200, 0);

        Color color = Color.White;
        vertices[0].Color = color;
        vertices[1].Color = color;
        vertices[2].Color = color;
        vertices[3].Color = color;

        vertices[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 0);
        vertices[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
        vertices[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(1, 1);
        vertices[3].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 1);

        GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionColorTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, vertices, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Do you insist on the texture coordinates being what you have them now? With a little math you could simply re-map the texture.

Comment: I don't understand how that will work; the four corners of the texture are directly related to the vertices; can you give an example of what math can solve the problem? Note that I chose the checkered pattern because it makes the 'problem' most obvious, in the game this will be an image not a repeated pattern.

Comment: Do you want the texture to be skewed like in the answer you linked to or do you want to preserve the aspect ratio of the texture?

Comment: I want the texture to be linear interpolated across the entire trapezoid instead of per triangle.

Comment: Found the solution on this very stack exchange: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/68021/how-can-i-draw-a-perspective-correct-quad

Comment: That's a first for me: someone voting to close his own question for duplicate :P

Comment: heh :-) Well, I stumbled on the solution while looking for something else. Strangely I wasn't able to find the answer at the time...